# How do I send jenkins build log as an attachment to a slack channel and JIRA

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jira, slack

I want to have the option to send the whole jenkins build log to a slack channel. I currently output the status of the builds successfully to slack, I would like to send the build log if the build fails. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried creating a shell script to zip up the log on the jenkins server and then posting it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Incoming WebHooks` or `Slash Commands` both are the same.

I'm also using both for sending my Jenkins to build artifact to slack channel but.

[image]

You can add an attachment also in this hooks or Jenkins generate URL for all build artifacts and you can just pass that URL on slack and user can download it via slack.

you have to user slack plugin on Jenkins and configure your slack token and stuff like that.

> If you need more detail [contact me](http://prashant007bhatasana@gmail.com).